# Container disk usage in DataDog

Tags: docker, containers, datadog

Is there any way to monitor disk usage of docker containers in DataDog?

I can see in DataDog web all the CPU, RAM and IO metrics for my containers.

But I can't see any of disk space related metrics.

Their page https://docs.datadoghq.com/integrations/docker/ says about:

```
docker.disk.used (now reported as docker.data.used)
docker.disk.free (now reported as docker.data.free)
docker.disk.total (now reported as docker.data.total)
```

I can't find these neither in Dashboards > Docker nor in Metrics > Explorer

I'm new to DataDog, so possibly missing something obvious here.

Comment: Datadog has online chat for all users, in most case, you get answer immediately. So why not ask this type of questions directly to them?

Comment: Good one. Found Slack chat, registered, joined containers channel, asked the question... whew... time to brew some tea.

Comment: @Ivan Did you get an answer?

Comment: They did reply to me in their Slack channel. Make it worth for me digging it up, by voting my question up :)

Comment: @gerarddp, I've posted my answer below, but bear in mind I haven't actually tested this, as we went instead all the way with Prometheus\Grafana

Answer (score 5):

There are 2 relevant options in `/etc/dd-agent/conf.d/docker_daemon.yaml`:

- **collect_disk_stats**
  If you use devicemapper-backed storage (which is default in ECS but not in vanilla Docker or Kubernetes), docker.data.* and docker.metadata.* statistics should do what you are looking for.
- **collect_container_size**
  A generic way, using the docker API but virtually running df in every container. This enables the docker.container.* metrics.

See more here:
https://help.datadoghq.com/hc/en-us/articles/115001786703-How-to-report-host-disk-metrics-when-dd-agent-runs-in-a-docker-container-

and here:
https://github.com/DataDog/docker-dd-agent/blob/master/conf.d/docker_daemon.yaml#L46